# How do you create date and time picker in onsenui?

Tags: angularjs, date, time, onsen-ui

How do you create date and time picker in onsenui?
I couldn't find any thing in their documentation and don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use html5 attribute like `date` and `time` to create datepicker in onsenui. for example

```
 <input type="date" class="text-input" ng-model="inputDate"/>
```

You can look more details in [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp)

Comment: I saw that but its really not not how i wanted it. Especially, the time picker part is not handy to for use. I was looking for a more user friendly component (if available).

Answer (score 0):

1. The easiest way is to use Monaca, the browser based IDE from the same OnsenUI's company. You can find how to add this dateTime picker in their [document](http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/en/reference/phonegap_plugin/datepicker/). This will work for both iOS and Android. You can also add OnsenUI and PhoneGap DateTime Picker plugin right from the IDE. Therefore, you don't need to add the plugin one by one. Below is the screenshot of the OnsenUI with Datetime Picker:

   https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgmk7b3e90nf75k/2014-09-02%2014.06.38.png?dl=0
2. [Here](http://bikasv.com/blog/2013/04/14/cordova-datepicker/) is how to add the dateTime picker for Android.

I hope this helps. Cheer.

Comment: thanks but I can't change IDE. I'm using VS2013 and I don't have any control to change it. Besides, i want this datetime picker to work the same on all major mobiles too, not just on android.

Comment: Then, you can just add DatePicker plugin into your project. https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/466. Then, follow the above tutorial.